# stmt PHP не сохраняет запрос INSERT INTO

Tags: php, sql

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'base');
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO `users`(`nick`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $nick, $email, $pass);
$email = 'test@test';
$nick = 'test';
$password = '12345';
$pass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

После этого ничего не появляется в базе и нет ошибок от PHP. В документации к PHP делали так же. Делал через stmt запросы SELECT, они нормально отрабатываются.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Спасибо, забыл, что 1 из параметров не имеет стандартного значения)